# JMeter: run parameterized threads

Tags: jmeter

I've written simple test plan in JMeter, plan consists of one thread group and one controller with "HTTP request" elemets. Plan performes login to website, session refresh and logout.
Is there a way to preform thread running, with different params (login/password) each time?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of different ways to parametrize your test.  If you have a lot of users you want to use, I would recommend using a [CSV Data Set Config](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config).  If you only have a few you want to use, you can try [User Defined Variables](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) or [User Parameters](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Parameters).  Make sure you check out the documentation, as each one is used slightly differently.